# Configure error when installing Arduino IDE

Tags: apt, arduino

I want to install Arduino IDE, version 1.5.4 BETA from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases#1.5.x). I need this specific version, but if I use the repository, it gives me the latest version (1.6.5), and I don't want that. When I download it, it's in .tgz format, and I managed to unpack it but I don't know how to install. The unpacked folder is still in /Downloads folder.

I tried ./configure but it gives me this error:

`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.

I do have the build-essential package installed.

Can anyone explain what the problem is and how can I install the files? All the other arduino-related questions on this site are about the latest version and they don't match my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded the `1.5.4` version and extracted the tar file.

The tar file contains a binary file already, which means that you don't have to install it, you'll only need to type `./arduino` to run that version(if you are in the extracted folder).

If you want to start the application from anywhere in the terminal you can create a soft link for the application from the `Downloads` folder.

1. From my understanding you don't want the latest version at all so purge that: `sudo apt-get purge arduino`
2. Create a soft link for the application, in this case I'll create it to the `/bin` folder. Use the full path to your `Downloads` folder, example: `sudo ln -s /home/yourusername/Downloads/arduino-1.5.4/arduino /bin/arduino`
3. Now type `arduino` in your terminal and it should start the application.

Hope this works for you, if not, leave a comment and I'll try to help you further.